# DNS for Tor hidden services

Tags: onion-services, help, dns

I have just discovered that DNS cannot be used by Tor hidden services, is that true?
Also is it possible to use DNS services of multiple servers to prevent server down time for Tor hidden service? I mean if one server goes down then the other secondary, or tertiary, servers can pick up the traffic flow of a Tor hidden service or not?

Comment: `DNS cannot be used by Tor hidden services` it is unclear what you mean by this. Tor HS's are not domain names. When you enter a `.onion` address in your browser, DNS is not involved. However, you could still put a `.onion` address in a DNS record (eg. an SRV record for something which also provides a hidden service) and clients which support Tor could recognize it. You may get better answers if you clarify your question. The second part about load balancing HS's, has been asked before. Please do a search. Thanks!

Comment: In simple words my question is about knowing how to prevent a downtime of a tor hidden service .Is it possible to use multiple servers for a tor hidden service.If the primary server goes down so the others will pick up ?